# SQL first of group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table:

```
ID | value1 |value2
1  | 15     | A
2  | 15     | B
3  | 16     | D
4  | 16     | A
5  | 16     | C
```

as outcome I would like to see only the first record of value1 (group by?)
like this:

```
ID | value1 |value2
1  | 15     | A
2  | 16     | D
```

I can do this with:

```
select * from vals
group by value1
```

Though, in SQL server, will I always be sure he takes the first record (with lowest ID) of the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually do this:

```
select * from vals
group by value1
```

because that won't even execute and it would bring back every row since the `ID` differs on each row. So, if you're trying to get the first row for each `value1` then you could do something like this:

```
select * from vals
where id in (select min(id) from vals group by value1)
```

and that would get you the first row of each **group** by `value1`.

Comment: Michael, that will not work, you can't have subquery introduced with IN return two columns. value1 is not needed there.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, yeah, thanks that was a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT MIN(id)AS id FROM vals
    GROUP BY value1 
)
SELECT vals.* FROM cte
INNER JOIN vals ON vals.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure  you can:

```
 Select * From vals v
 Where id = (Select Min(id)
             From vals 
             Where value1 = v.value1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use windowing functions (`row_number()`) to get the result:

```
select id, value1, value2
from
(
  select id, value1, value2,
    row_number() over(partition by value1 order by id) rn
  from vals
) d
where rn = 1;
```

Or you can use a subquery:

```
select v1.id, v1.value1, v1.value2
from vals v1
inner join
(
  select min(id) id, value1
  from vals
  group by value1
) v2
  on v1.id = v2.id
  and v1.value1 = v2.value1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b80c5/4) of both queries